# R - 2 fun same code, one works and one gives $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

i know might of u think this question and duplicated,but i do really have something kinda freaks me out, i was learning R and i had assignment to do something i do manage to solve it but i wonder why this error appear while the 2 code is very similar, is that something i don't understand in R

the first who has give me an error was :

```
    makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
    #i for invirse
    i <- NULL
    set <- function(y){
        x <<- y
        i <<- NULL 
    }
    get <- function(){x}
    setinv <- function(solved){i <<- solved}
    getinv <- function(){i}
    #a list that has the 4 internal methods
    list(set = set, get = get,
         setinv = setinv,
         getinv = getinv)
}

## Write a short comment describing this function
# this method check first if the data already cached,
# if they are it return it with message says "Getting cached data"
# if not it calculated, cache it and then return it
cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
    ## Return a matrix that is the inverse of 'x'
    i <- x$getinv()
    if(!is.null(i)){
        message("Getting cached data")
        return(i)
    }
    #calculate the inverse 
    x <- x$get()
    i <- solve(x)
    #print(i)
    #print(class(i))
    x$setinv(i)
    i
}
```

this is how i call my function and the only result i get is 
ps uncomment the print and clas funs will give the correct answers:

```
> source('~/R/cachematrix[not workng].R')
> x <- makeCacheMatrix(matrix(rnorm(16), 4,4))
> cacheSolve(x)
Error in x$setinv : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

after some time i said to myself why using too match variable and i use the methods inside each other for more sample code (one line is better)
but somehow the code works, for me it's the same code the only thing i have did the to pass the methods to each other instead of passing it into variable then pass the variable to method (it's the same really)
the code became like this now :

```
    ## Write a short comment describing this function
# this method retuen a matrix that has a list
# this list has 4 method as getters and sitters
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
    #i for invirse
    i <- NULL
    set <- function(y){
        x <<- y
        i <<- NULL 
    }
    get <- function(){x}
    setinv <- function(solved){i <<- solved}
    getinv <- function(){i}
    #a list that has the 4 internal methods
    list(set = set, get = get,
         setinv = setinv,
         getinv = getinv)
}

## Write a short comment describing this function
# this method check first if the data alredy cached,
# if they are it return it with messege sys "Getting cached data"
# if not it calculated, cache it and then return it
cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
    ## Return a matrix that is the inverse of 'x'
    i <- x$getinv()
    if(!is.null(i)){
        message("Getting cached data")
        return(i)
    }
    #calculate the invirse 
    i <- solve(x$get())
    #cache the invirse for later
    x$setinv(i)
    i
}
```

and this's how i call my function:

```
> source('~/R/ProgrammingAssignment2/cachematrix.R')
> x <- makeCacheMatrix(matrix(rnorm(16), 4,4))
> cacheSolve(x)
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  0.09904578 -0.4586855 -0.2487849 -0.3421875
[2,] -1.84896897  0.8476203  0.7990204  0.5919526
[3,]  0.70645287 -0.1508695 -0.7141914 -0.2729974
[4,]  1.37441746 -0.9853108 -0.5607929  0.6553295
```

works good, i just wanna know what happen there, and why the first code give me an error and the second one didn't while both suppose to have the same logic, Thanks in advance mates

ps. i'm using : R version 3.3.2 on linux mint 18.1 with the latest version of rstudio

Comment: In the line `x <- x$get()` the code is overwriting the list `x` with a matrix and then subsequently the code tries to use $ on that matrix.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck wow, i didn't notice that at all, Thanks mate that was really great observation from u